# Why did the fill valve in my toilet pop up?

Tags: toilet

The fill valve in one of my toilets popped up with enough force that it lifted the toilet cover up and nearly off the toilet. Anyone heard of this happening, and any ideas what might have caused it? I pushed it down and it clicked, and now everything works again (see picture).

My best and only guess is that it has something to do with in-tank toilet cleaner thing that was in there (we moved in recently, I didn't know it was there). Maybe it was floating around free and got caught on something? I'm not sure, this all happened when I wasn't in the room.

Bottom line is I'm probably going to replace the fill valve, I'm just wondering if anyone has any insight into what might have happened.

[image: picture]

Comment: Note that most toilet manufacturers advise against the in-tank cleaners since they tend to degrade the seals (I do note that you removed it, which is good.)

Answer (score 2):

These fill valves are adjustable in height for various toilets

Ther is a simple way to lock it at the appropriate  height this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIuC4UVXgBQ) will help

Comment: Yeah, that sort of thing (unless it repeats after you've twisted it into place properly) is not a "must replace it ASAP" but usually just a "poorly assembled or adjusted and popped loose" situation.

Comment: Though the ones that "shoot up" are more commonly just a 1/4 or 1/8 turn to lock, and the opposite way to free (which is why they shoot up due to water pressure on the intake) while the one in your video is a "screw adjust" model that would be unlikely to "shoot up."

Comment: Thanks for the information, all. I think it must have just been a fluke of some kind. I'm going to fiddle with it a bit more, see if it happens again, and then probably replace the fill valve when convenient.